# Driver installation problems in macOS Big Sur (in this case CP210x USB bridge)

Tags: macos-big-sur

i wanted to connect my micro controller to macOS Big Sur. For that I need a CP2104 / CP210x USB bridge driver, but I can't install it. In macOS X it was not a problem to install it.

I found [this information](https://www.silabs.com/community/interface/forum.topic.html/vcp_driver_for_macosbigsur110x-SWJK) on the website of silabs. They still work on a new driver.

Does anyone know a workaround for this problem until there is a new driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 12/22, a new v6.0 driver is posted. However, it's still defective IME and not loading the kext on MacOS 11.1. Please feel free to open a support case at https://siliconlabs.force.com/s/contactsupport